# NodeJs & Googleapis: youtube api insert throwing error 0 mime parts in multipart request

Tags: node.js, google-api, youtube-api

I'm trying to use nodejs to upload to youtube using the googleapi module and I have authentication and all that running but whenever I try to use the youtube api to insert I get `Error: Invalid multipart request with 0 mime parts.`

This is the code I'm using to do the upload

```
function uploadVideo(videoPath, userData, videoData){

oauth2Client.credentials = {
    access_token: userData.access_token,
    refresh_token: userData.refresh_token
};

const youtube = google.youtube({
  version: 'v3',
  auth: oauth2Client
});

console.log("YOUTUBE: " + youtube)


const req = youtube.videos.insert({
    part: 'id,snippet,status',
    notifySubscribers: false,
    resource: {
      snippet: {
        title: videoData.title,
        description: videoData.description
      },
      status: {
        privacyStatus: 'private'
      }
    },
    media: {
        body: fs.createReadStream(videoPath)
    }
  }, (err, data) => {
    if (err) {
      throw err;
    }
    console.log(data);
    fs.unlink(videoPath, function(err){ if(err) return console.log(err); });  
  });
```

I tried to downgrade the googleapis package but whenever I do that my `const {google} = require('googleapis');` just returns an undefined object

Also it seems to go through only one time if I empty out the mongodb with the user auth credentials but after that it just keeps giving that error.

Comment: In your situation, was there the case that no error of ``Error: Invalid multipart request with 0 mime parts.`` occurs?

Comment: @Tanaike The only time it doesn't occur is when I reset the token/refresh token and get a new one, but after using it once it gives me that error. I set it up now so that with each request it gets a new token using the request token and it seems to be pretty reliable but I'm not sure if thats the right thing to do.

Comment: I think that retrieving the access token using refresh token every time is a common way. But I don't think that retrieving the refresh token every time is a common way. In my case, such error could be removed by downgrading googleapis to v24. Your case may be difference with my case. I'm sorry for my incomplete comment. By the way, when you downgrage googleapis, had you modified to ``const google = require('googleapis');``?

Comment: @Tanaike Yea whenever I downgraded to v24 the line `const google = require('googleapis');` just returns an undefined object.

Comment: In my environment, ``const google = require('googleapis');`` works at googleapis with v24. I'm sorry for this situation.